# CAST(date AS DATE) date format

Tags: mysql, date, casting

I have following php routine to extract values from a table. I'm trying to convert the `DATE` type from "2014-08-10", value to "20140810", value

Rtn:

```
//query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), EtotalDay from MonthData group by 1 order by 1") 
OR die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());

//write the results
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {echo  $row['CAST(date AS DATE)'] . "," . $row['EtotalDay'] . "\n";
```

Haw can I do this?

Comment: Do something like `select cast(...) as FormattedDate...`. That way when you do mysqli_fetch_array you can use $row['FormattedDate']. You can then do formatting in PHP. Also, do not use mysql_ functions. [Use mysqli_ functions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d')
```

instead of CAST(), complete with an column alias name for the retrieving of the field

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d') formattedDate, EtotalDay from MonthData group by 1 order by 1") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());


//write the results
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {echo  $row['formattedDate'] . "," . $row['EtotalDay'] . "\n";
```

see the manual, [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

> DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
>
> Formats the date value according to the format string.
>
> The following specifiers may be used in the format string. The “%”
>   character is required before format specifier characters.
>
> %d Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
>   %m Month, numeric (00..12)
>   %Y Year, numeric, four digits

Comment: Missed that part. Give this column a nice name, so you can use that with mysql_fetch_array. I've just edited that in.